# iterate through floating numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby, math

I have the following code:

```
float_number = 0.01
while first_number < 0.10 do
float_number += 0.01
puts first_number
end
```

This results in:

```
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
0.060000000000000005
0.07
0.08
0.09
0.09999999999999999
0.10999999999999999
```

This is sorta correct. Is there an effective way to insure I am not getting a bunch of extra digits?

Comment: As your output shows, there is something more going on. Floats are not always 100% precise to decimal numbers. This is not simple to fix, so what are you looking for - nice output, perfect precise 1/100ths, or something else?

Comment: Use [`Float#round`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html#method-i-round) — e.g. `(0.060000000000000005).round(2) #=> 0.06` (to the nearest hundredth)

Comment: If you're asking why it's giving you `0.060000000000000005` instead of `0.06` in the first place, see also every question on this site about floating point values, and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BigDecimal` for precision arithmetic maybe...

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Actually, standard library in new versions http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/

Comment: Ah. I see. Very good, then. You should add that link to your answer.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Actually, not so new at all http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html

Comment: Right you are. I had never noticed that — just assumed there were no `Numeric` types outside of the core. +1 for teaching me something I didn't know.